# Regex split on keywords

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a string and want to split it into an array.

I'm not a RegEx guru, but I've already tried "\s((?:AND|OR|NOT)\(.*?\))\s"

string:

```
"free part AND(\"and part\") OR(or part) NOT(\"not part AND\") AND(another and) NOT(\"nospace\") AND(\"not(ugly part)\")"
```

array:

```
"free part"
"AND(\"and part\")"
"OR(or part)"
"NOT(\"not part AND\")"
"AND(another and)"
"NOT(\"nospace\")"
"AND(\"not(ugly part)\")"
```

It'a .NET C# program.

Comment: What do you want to use?  sed, C, perl?

Comment: You forgot to post what you already tried.

Comment: It seems that perhaps some kind of parser might be better suited to this than regular expressions.

Comment: From the tags, it looks like it's C#

Comment: Use online REGEX tools to create and test your regex. http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm http://regexpal.com/   for C# http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Dmitry, It's funny that regexhero.net/tester gives me the right outcome, but when I run in my concole app, boom, it won't work...

Comment: Sorry @Ostati, I've tried your regex and it looks working for me, where mystring is your string: var lines = Regex.Split(mystring, @"\s((?:AND|OR|NOT)\(.*?\))\s");

Comment: Try this string "free text NOT(\"my search\") OR(\"something\") NOT(\"not part\")"

Comment: For some reason, RegEx needs even number of AND OR NOT.. Otherwise i won't work!

Comment: I agree with @Mark Wilkins you should create parser for this pourpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along this lines? (I haven't tested this)

regex:

```
\s(?=(AND|OR|NOT)[^)]*)
```

replacement string:

```
"\n"
```

Comment: Added non-capturing and it works \s(?=(?:AND|OR|NOT)[^)]*?). Also fixed mine \s{1}((?:AND|OR|NOT)\(.*?\))\s{0,1}

Comment: RegEx messes up when I put AND, OR or NOT inside like so: NOT(\"not AND part\"). Is there a way around this?

Comment: This regex should cover those cases as well, and it's also simpler: `\s(?=(AND|OR|NOT)\()`

Comment: Thanks ale84! The problem is in the query itself, when you put another "AND(" or "AND()" inside another AND like so: AND("and query AND(").. BTW, your RegEx is missing the non-capturing so I refactored it to "\s(?=(?:AND|OR|NOT)\()"